# Twitter text retrieval with new 280 character system

Tags: twitter, google-apps-script

Using Google Scripts, I have a program that retrieves the text from one account's tweets and uses it for various other things. It's been running for over a year with minimal issues, but now the tweets are being adjusted to 280 characters and I can't retrieve the second half of the tweet. I have:

```
 function refreshing_v2() {


  var service = getTwitterService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {

var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=(redacted)&count=1&include_rts=0&exclude_replies=1';

var response = service.fetch(url);
var tweets = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {

  //Parse the tweet
  var latest = new String(tweets[i].text); 
  var maxi_id = tweets[i].id;
  var startpos = latest.indexOf("1: ");
```

etc, etc, continues doing stuff with what it's found.

This allows me to get the FIRST half of the text. What's retrieved looks something like "[Content of first half]...(link to tweet)"

How do I get the full text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `tweet_mode=extended` to get the full text in the response. You may need to check the entities you receive to see if it is what you are expecting.

Documentation link - https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates

Additionally, you will need to use `full_text` rather than just `text`

So:

```
//Parse the tweet
var latest = new String(tweets[i].full_text);
```

See the sample tweet at https://github.com/twitterdev/tweet-updates/blob/master/samples/initial/compatibilityplus_extended_13997.json

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly where to put that. this program was inherited from someone else, so I admit I'm a little shaky on the pulling from twitter syntax. I tried adding &tweet_mode=extended to the url declaration and it just returned "undefined" instead of either the truncated tweet OR the full one.

Comment: Can you add the full code of your program? Edit the question so we can see exactly what's going on.

Comment: Edited with the full beginning of the function.

Comment: I've edited my answer. You should be using `full_text` when you parse the tweet

Comment: That makes latest return as undefined.